# Memory error while implementing BFS(Breadth First Search)

Tags: c

I am trying to implement BFS of graph.
These are my header files-

**nodes.h**

```
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct Queue
{
    Node * front;
    Node * rear;
}Queue;
```

**control.h**

```
#include"nodes.h"
Queue * CreateQueue();
int isEmptyQueue(Queue * Q);
void EnQueue(Queue * Q,int data);
int DeQueue(Queue * Q);
void DeleteQueue(Queue * Q);
```

This is my code which implements the queue to be used for BFS(breadth first search).This works fine when I run it without my BFS code.But with BFS code it gives memory allocation error(I have mentioned my error at the last of my question)in the function `CreateQueue()` when I allocate memory for the `Queue`.

**queue.c**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include"control.h"


Queue * CreateQueue()
{
    Queue * Q;
    Node * temp;
    Q=(Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));printf("Hello\n");
    if(!Q)
    return NULL;

    temp=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    Q->front=Q->rear=NULL;
    return Q;
}

int isEmptyQueue(Queue * Q)
{
    return(Q->front==NULL);
}

void EnQueue(Queue * Q,int data)
{
    Node * newNode;
    newNode=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->data=data;
    newNode->next=NULL;


    if(Q->rear)
        Q->rear->next=newNode;
    if(Q->front==NULL)
        Q->front=Q->rear=newNode;
}

int DeQueue(Queue * Q)
{
    int data;
    Node * temp;
    if(isEmptyQueue(Q))
     return 0;
    else
        {
            temp=Q->front;
            data=Q->front->data;    
            Q->front=temp->next;
            //free(temp);
        }
        return data;
}
```

This is my BFS code which makes use of `queue.c`

**BFS.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"control.h"

typedef struct Graph
{
  int V;
  int E;
  int * visited;
  int * vis;
  int ** Adj;
}Graph;


Graph * adjMatrix()
{
    int i,j,v2,v1;

    Graph * G = (Graph *)malloc(sizeof(Graph));

    FILE * input;

    input=fopen("input.txt","r");
    fscanf(input,"%d",&G->V);
    fscanf(input,"%d",&G->E);
    G->Adj = (int **)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int *));
    G->visited = (int *)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int ));
    G->vis = (int *)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int ));
    for (i=1; i<=G->V; i++)
         G->Adj[i] = (int *)malloc(G->V * sizeof(int));
    for(i=1;i<=G->V;i++)
    {
      for(j=1;j<=G->V;j++)
        {   
            G->Adj[i][j]=0;

        }
    }
    fscanf(input,"%d %d",&v1,&v2);
    while(!feof(input))
      {


            G->Adj[v1][v2]=1;
            G->Adj[v2][v1]=1;
            fscanf(input,"%d %d",&v1,&v2);
      }

    return G;
}


void BFS(Graph * G,int u)
{   
    int i;
    Queue * Q=CreateQueue();
    EnQueue(Q,u);
    while(!isEmptyQueue(Q))
        {
            u=DeQueue(Q);
            printf("%d\n",u);
            //Process v
            G->visited[u]=1;
            for(i=1;i<=G->V;i++)
                {
                    if(!G->visited[i] && G->Adj[u][i]==1)
                        EnQueue(Q,i);
                }
        }
}

int main()
{   
    Graph * G=adjMatrix();
    int i,j,k,count=0;

    //Display the graph
    for(i=1;i<=G->V;i++)
     {
        for(j=1;j<=G->V;j++)
          printf("%d  ",G->Adj[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
     }

     BFS(G,3);
}
```

I am using matrix representaion and am taking input from the file.The code is correct the  problem is when I call `CreateQueue`in BFS.I get runtime error as this-

**Error**

```
exe: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: I tried that also.Even then it gives the same error.When I run the same code of `queue.c` alone it gives correct result but with BFS it gives the above mentioned error.

Comment: That was a _suggestion_, not an answer to your problem, BTW. :-)

Comment: I would advise you to use Valgrind: http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/QuickStart.html
1) Install valgrind
2) Compile your programme in debug mode (-g flag with gcc)
3) Run valgrind ./your-program-executable --leak-check=full
You will get a list of invalid writes / reads you're making

Comment: I dont know what happened.The same code executed correctly after a system restart.